# what can a computer do without an operation system

Tags: operating-system, system, operation

An operation system is a program that controls all the other programs so that the user can manipulate he's work.
What will happen if the os seize to exist?
Could the user still be able to perform some tasks or not?

Comment: It can blink its lights.

Comment: Well, it will display you an error on your display.

Comment: 'program that controls all the other programs' sorta.  It's more of a resource manager, controlling access to CPU. memory, disk, networks, KB, mouse, display etc.  If your computer system has only one application with only one  thread of execution, then it can freely use all the resources, and the need for an OS disappears.

Answer (score 0):

The OS is not just needed to control other programs, but also to do all the heavy-lifting involved with dealing with the hardware, so the actual programs don't have to do it or even know about it.

The user can do whatever his programs allow him to do, while the programs **need** the operating system to function properly (or at all). If there where no OS, all the programs would have to do everything that OS was doing for them before (which is A LOT).

Among many things that OS does the most important for the user is that it allows to run several programs simultaneously without them interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Computers do not need operating systems. If the computer does not have an operating system, the application needs to perform the operating system functions. Such applications as operating systems used to be more common than they are today. They are most common in real-time systems where the computer is performing only one general function.